# typescript error when I tried to destructuring an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I made a react app with create-react-app typescript template.
I made a simple card component, and I tried to destructuring an object but i have the following error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yeof.png)

this is my tsconfig file

```html
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target":"ES2020",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module":"ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` is a reserved keyword used in switch statements. Any other name will be fine.

```
interface CardProps {
    default: 'test';
    defaults: 'test';
}

declare const props: CardProps;

const { default } = props; // KO
const { defaults } = props; // OK
```

[See other reserved keywords](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords).

Comment: as per https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: thanks @Matthieu, it was a rookie mistake